# docker-compose command wait-for looks like not holding the start of the service

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

i followed the example [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) and made wait_for  script (tested and its working) :

```
#!/bin/bash

container_name="$1"
c=1
until docker container ls --filter "name=$container_name" --filter "status=running" | grep healthy; do
        >&2 echo "server is unavailable - sleeping"
        sleep 5
        ((c=c+1))
        echo "$c"
        if [[ "$c" -eq 20 ]] ;then
          echo "exit"
          exit 1;
        fi
done
```

now in my docker-compose file, i have something like this :

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  app1:
    image: x
    container_name: "xx"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 222
    networks:
      - x_network

  app2:
    image: "y"
    container_name: "y2"
    depends_on:
      - app1
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "xx"]
    ports:
      - 8444
   
    links:
      - app1
    networks:
      - x_network

networks:
  x_network:
    driver: bridge
```

But when I start  i don't see app2 waiting, can i see some logs to verify the script is working ?

Comment: Your script is using `docker` commands, but the script is running as the command/entrypoint for app2. I would expect your app2 container to fail running `docker container ls`. Try adding `set -x` and `set -e` at the top of your script and trying again. You should see some helpful output after your container crashes (`docker logs y2`).

Comment: its is checking if app1 is ready not checking it self

Comment: Yes, that's your intention, but only the host can use `docker` commands to query container state. Your script is running within the app2 container, so it will not have access to `docker` commands.